# Rectify PathTraversal found in AppScan Tool

Tags: java

I ran IBM AppScan tool on a java source. It has listed few findings under 'PathTraversal - Promote to Vulnerability' on the line "pageFile = new File(fileName);". Can I know what is the solution to rectify this ?

```
package mig;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.channels.FileChannel;

import mig.one.GenConstants;
import mig.one.GenInit;
import mig.one.GenException;
import mig.one.GenExpConstants;
import mig.one.GenLogger;

public class Generate {

    private static final String EVENT_TYPE  ="EXTENSION_XML";

    private static GenLogger logger = GenLogger.getLogger();

    public static void main(String[] args) throws GenException {

        GenInit genMigration = new GenInit(args);
        genMigration.parseArguments(args);

        File pageFile=null;
        String fileName = null;

        try{
            if(args[1].equalsIgnoreCase("-f")){

                fileName    =   GenConstants.MAP_FILE;
                logger.logDebug(EVENT_TYPE, "Menu Map File name ::"+ fileName);

                pageFile = new File(fileName);
                }
            }
            catch(GenException ume) {

            logger.logError(EVENT_TYPE, ume.getMessage(),ume);
            throw ume;
            } catch(Throwable th)   {

            logger.logError(EVENT_TYPE, th.getMessage(), th);
            throw new GenException(GenExpConstants.EM_UNKNOWN, new String[]{th.getMessage()},th);
            } finally {
            logger.logDebug(EVENT_TYPE, "####################################################\n");
            }
    }
}
```

In the above code 
GenConstants.MAP_FILE = System.getProperty("user.dir") + File.separator +"file.cfg";

Answer (score 0):

You will need to inspect the trace data for this Finding.  Based on your update, I believe the taint is coming from the `user.dir` property and that this value is not sanitized.